# How to purge old records from RDS postgres database table?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm using a RDS instance(v 11.9) which runs postgres db and i need to delete old records from a table. As per my study, it seems like we can create an event trigger to delete the old records when an insertion occurs. But the trigger will be made for each and every frequent insertions which cause unnecessary traffic. So are there any effective solution for this (ie any inbuilt automatic deletion methods or scheduled jobs)?

FYI, the table contains a timestamp column

Comment: Postgres does not have a native built in scheduler. You can investigate the extension [pg_cron](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL_pg_cron.html) or invoke a script from an OS scheduler. BTW the trigger idea is a very bad one.